# Loop not working - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason this Array isnt working! What could be wrong? Basically it is supposed to loop through every worksheet and give the same header to each worksheet.

```
WorksheetNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
For Each ws In WorksheetNames
    With Worksheets(ws)
        .Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "PSTRIK"
        .Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "PRECID"
        .Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "PEXCH"
        .Range("J1").FormulaR1C1 = "PQTY"
        .Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "PCTYM"
        .Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "PFC"
        .Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "PACCT"
        .Range("K1").FormulaR1C1 = "PPRTCP"
        .Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "PSUBTY"
        .Range("H1").FormulaR1C1 = "PSBCUS"
        .Range("I1").FormulaR1C1 = "PBS"
    End With
Next ws
```

Comment: Does it work for sheets named "Sheet1" and "Sheet2"?  Those are the only sheets you have specified to put these headers in.  Do you actually have sheets named "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" in your workbook?

Comment: `Dim ws as Worksheet` and `For Each ws in Worksheets` (this will do *all* worksheets). This appears to be, essentially a typo, voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: What isn't working? Does it loop? Are there error messages?

Comment: @tigerayater There are actually 16 more worksheets, I just put "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" to save space. The worksheets' actual names are not Sheet1 and Sheet2, but it is just easier to type on here.

Comment: well you're going to have to help us out here.If you put a breakpoint on your loop and step through using F8, what happens?

Comment: There's typos in your array.  The code, as you posted here, works fine.  Triple check the worksheet names, and make sure there aren't any leading or trailing spaces.  Otherwise, we can't reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect something like this is what you're looking for:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aHeaders As Variant

    aHeaders = Array("PRECID", "PACCT", "PEXCH", "PFC", "PSUBTY", "PSTRIK", "PCTYM", "PSBCUS", "PBS", "PQTY", "PPRTCP")

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            'any worksheet names listed here won't have their headers updated
            Case "NoUpdate", "Leave Alone"
                'Do nothing

            'Update headers for all other sheets
            Case Else
                ws.Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(aHeaders) - LBound(aHeaders) + 1).Value = aHeaders
        End Select
    Next ws

End Sub
```